# What is the advantage of SSVP docking mechanism?

Tags: docking-port

Sistema Stykovki i Vnutrennego Perekhoda (SSVP) is a probe-and-drogue docking mechanism widely used in Soviet and Russian manned spaceflight.

Comparing to the Androgynous Peripheral Attach System (APAS) and the Common Berthing Mechanism (CBM), SSVP provided neither androgynous docking interface nor a wide passage.

What is the advantage of SSVP?

Answer (score 1):

It was lighter.

APAS was of much greater mass when it came to attaching it to Soyuz, which meant that they had to sacrifice a cosmonaut/payload.

Less of an issue when it came to the Soviet Space Shuttle but world events took a different turn anyway.

NB, you cannot dock with a CBM, only berth.